# Error exporting CSV (or XML) when there is a subreport inside another subreport (SSRS)

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), I have a mainReport A that contains a subreport B. This subreport B has another subreport C.

When I try to export to CSV (or XML) another tab is open saying that it occurred an error (Error: Subreport could not be shown. (rrRenderingError)).
The exporting works fine when subReport B has data. The error showed up only when the datasource of subreportB does not collect data.
Anyone already had the same problem?

Thank you,

Hélder Antunes

Answer (score 0):

A workaround that I use for this was the disabling of rendering of the subreports of the 2nd level using the element [DataElementOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/rendering-data-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15) (hidden conditions did not work):

```
<TablixCell>
  <DataElementOutput>NoOutput</DataElementOutput>
  <CellContents>  
    <Subreport Name="xpto">
      <ReportName>xpto</ReportName>
      <Parameters>
```

Since I did not use any hidden condition, the subreports of the 2nd level are shown in the main view and in another formats.